# How to pass a php variable in WHERE clause of SELECT statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a php variable that I want to fetch another field in database using this variable in my *where* clause.

My code:

```
require("conn.php");
$module = $_POST[ 'postmodule' ];
$query = "SELECT width FROM modules WHERE code = $module";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['width'];
```

But this is printing me nothing. Don't know where I am going wrong but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the query works if ran directly from the database? Is there some error message you can post that we can look into?

Comment: Should this line be:      $query = "SELECT width FROM modules WHERE code =  '" + $module + "'";

Comment: Can you module name be have spaces in it? If so you have to wrap it with single quote mark as @Eric suggested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either break the string and concatenate the variable with `".."`

```
require("conn.php");
$module = $_POST[ 'postmodule' ];
$query = "SELECT width FROM modules WHERE code = '".$module."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['width'];
```

Or you could wrap the variable in `{}` within the string, as long as the string is wrapped in double quotes.

```
require("conn.php");
$module = $_POST[ 'postmodule' ];
$query = "SELECT width FROM modules WHERE code = '{$module}'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['width'];
```

Also, if `$module` is a string you will need to wrap the variable in single quotes as I did above.

Comment: You made my day. Thanks now i got it, it was a mix of string and numbers. I used your second method and everything worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

write after Connection code below statement

$fieldname = $_POST[ 'fieldname' ];