# Making a Variable Global To MySQL Query in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have declared a global variable like this in functions.php file

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$dept = $current_user->Department;
```

I want the Variable $dept to be used in my below query for filtering data output, So the Query look like this

```
SELECT P.ID, MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'first_name', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Name, MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'last_name', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Last, MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'Gender', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Gender, MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'Department', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Department, MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'position_title', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Dpt, MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'region', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Region, MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'district_dar', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS District, MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'status_av', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Status 
FROM wp_users AS P 
  LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS PM on PM.user_id = P.ID 
WHERE P.ID in (select user_id from wp_usermeta where meta_key='Department' and (meta_value = '$dept')) and P.ID in (select user_id from wp_usermeta where meta_key='status_av' and meta_value = 'on') 
group by P.ID
```

`$dept` as seen in the where clause but when you run the query it return nothing, any advice where i'm doing wrong will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a php variable in WHERE clause of SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52884131/how-to-pass-a-php-variable-in-where-clause-of-select-statement)

Comment: Not related to your problem, but per the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_currentuserinfo/), `get_currentuserinfo` is deprecated and [`wp_get_current_user`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) should be used instead.

Comment: Let me try wp_get_current_user

Comment: @disinfor its different question

Comment: @GeofreyMartin is it a different question? You said your query doesn't work, and based on the duplicate answer, it looks like you are passing the `$dept` variable incorrectly to the `WHERE` clause.